# Contact List can't be created in Sitecore 9 Update 2

Tags: list-manager

Trying to create empty Contact List in Sitecore 9 Update 2 through List Manager but getting 403 HTTP response code and below exception.

Request URL is `https://sc9u2.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/ListManagement/ContactList`

__RequestVerificationToken is part of Request headers. I have already tried it in latest Chrome and Firefox but no difference.
In IE11 it is working...

Exception:

```
Message : An error has occurred.

ExceptionMessage :  The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

ExceptionType : System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException

StackTrace : at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken) at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken) at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me looks like this is a Sitecore bug. 
As far I see Chrome, Firefox and IE works differently on validating tokens.

On Sitecore is a setting IsAuthorizationBypassAllowed. This setting, when set to true will ignore Request Validation checking on Controllers where the ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken attribute is set.

Please create a patch file for :

```
<setting name="Sitecore.Web.IsAuthorizationBypassAllowed" value="true" />
```

**@Pete Navara** created a blogpost about this issue and he described it like an **EXM wizard** :

@https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/11/10/bypassing-sitecores-request-verification/

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Worked like charm. Even Forms finally appeared in list and Experience Analytics is also showing graphs without weird exceptions.

Comment: Is this still bug on Sitecore or is it fixed? I'm facing same issue and tried the patch seems to fix the issue but I'm concerned about security ramification.